# Using Sierra MC7304 LTE modem with QMI

Tags: networking, drivers, modem

I am using a Sierra MC7304 LTE modem on my ALIX-Board with Ubuntu. As far as I understand there are two ways to use it:

- creating a ppp connection via `/dev/ttyUSB2` using e.g. `wvdial` (not suitable for LTE because of the serial interface limitations)
- connecting via qmi

Currently the modem is using `GobiNet`/`GobiSerial` drivers that create `/dev/ttyUSB0-2` devices that work with `wvdial`.

```
usb-devices
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1199 ProdID=68c0 Rev=00.06
S:  Manufacturer=Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
S:  Product=MC7304
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=GobiSerial
/usr/bin/usb-devices: line 79: printf: a: invalid number
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=GobiNet
/usr/bin/usb-devices: line 79: printf: b: invalid number
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=GobiSerial
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=GobiSerial
I:  If#= 8 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=GobiNet
```

My intention is to connect using qmi to achieve better data rates.

For this, I have loaded `qmi_wwan` via modprobe. My understanding is that loading this module should create a device `/dev/cdc-wdm` that can be used to connect via qmi. However, no such device appears. Removing the `GobiNet`/`GobiSerial` modules via `rmmod` only leaves the modem without any drivers at all.

Can someone please tell me how I can use MC7304 with qmi? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the GobiNet driver before loading qmi_wwan for the probing to work. The devices will be named /dev/cdc-wdm0 and /dev/cdc-wdm1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I haven't noticed it over the weekend. The problem that I was having wasn't solvable with the information I provided (sorry for that too). I was using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (upgrading to a newer verson is a pain because of the non-pae CPU) that did not support MC7304 in `qmi_wwan`.  I have replaced the `qmi_wwan` module with a newer one which solved the issue. The order in which I inserted/removed the modules was part of the problem too though.